# Xamarin.Android Notification.Notify does nothing

Tags: java, android, xamarin, notifications, xamarin.android

I am trying to show local notification using the standard android API:

```
var message = intent.GetStringExtra("message");
        var title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");

        var notIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
        var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, notIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
        var manager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(context);

        var style = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        style.BigText(message);

        int resourceId = Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher;

        var wearableExtender = new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
                .SetBackground(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(context.Resources, resourceId));

        //Generate a notification with just short text and small icon
        var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .SetContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .SetContentTitle(title)
                        .SetContentText(message)
                        .SetStyle(style)
                        .SetWhen(Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis())
                        .SetAutoCancel(true)
                        .Extend(wearableExtender);

        var notification = builder.Build();
        manager.Notify(0, notification);
```

I tried different versions of the notification creation but none of them does anything. It is like if it never was called but it does get called. 
I am testing on:
Samsung Galaxy s8
Android 8.0
Target SDK 8.1 (Oreo)

Do I miss anything to add in manifest or is it about new notification channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using channels on Oreo+ devices (API-26+).

Something like:

```
Notification ForegroundNotification(string title, string message)
{
    using (var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(ApplicationContext))
    {
        var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(ApplicationContext)
                                          .SetContentTitle(title)
                                                        .SetContentText(message)
                                                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_notification_network_locked)
                                                        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel channel;
            var channelName = ApplicationContext.PackageName;
            channel = notificationManager.GetNotificationChannel(channelName);
            if (channel == null)
            {
                channel = new NotificationChannel(channelName, channelName, NotificationImportance.Default)
                {
                    LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public
                };
                notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
            channel.Dispose();
            notificationBuilder = notificationBuilder
                                              .SetChannelId(channelName);
        }
        return notificationBuilder.Build();
    }
}
```

So your `NotificationManager.Notify` could become:

```
manager.Notify(0, ForegroundNotification("StackOverflow", "Totally Rocks"));
```

Comment: thank you it worked! Why could not they create a default channel automatically for developers who do not want to use it at all...